# Does Every Continuous Function Have an Antiderivative?

Tags: functional-analysis

I was thinking about integrals over continuous function and wanted to know if every continuous function has an antiderivative. Generally, the only way I can think of proving this is through a linear algebra approach.

I wanted to first prove or disprove

> Let $D_{x}$ be the differential operator, $C^{1}$ be the set of differentiable functions thats derivative is one time continuous, and $C$ be set of continous functions.
>
> $$C\subseteq D_{x}(C^{1})$$

and then if this were true then wanted to prove or disprove

> $D_{x}$ is surjection from $C^{1}$ to $C$

The problem is first I don't know if truth of the propositions would imply that every continuous function has an antiderivative. Next, Im not really comfortable with infinite subspaces. I know that if this did happen to be finite we could use rank nullity theorem and since constant function derivative would be 0 thus in nullspace thus not injective thus not surjective, but I'm pretty sure this type of logic doesn't apply to infinite subspaces.

Also If I didn't state these propositions correctly feel free to edit them

Comment: Bit of a tangent, but to follow up on your comment about infinite vector spaces: Injectivity and surjectivity are not equivalent in the infinite case. For example, the right shift operator $(x_1, x_2, \dots) \to (0, x_1, x_2, \dots)$ is injective but not surjective, and the left shift operator $(x_1, x_2, \dots) \to (x_2, \dots)$ is surjective but not injective.

Answer (score -1):

No, e.g., the Cantor function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function is a.e., constant, so that its derivative is a.e. $0$, although it is not constant, i.e., you cannot recover the function from its derivative. It is a canonical example of a function thatis integrable, but without an antiderivative.  I think what you are looking for is for the function to be absolutely-continuous, which will guarantee the existence of an antiderivative.

Comment: Ok thanks, even though my proposition's aren't true, if they did happen to be true with this prove that every continuous function has an antiderivative (wanted to know if my approach was right)

Comment: @user159813: do you mean to show that every absolutely-continuous function has an antiderivative?

Comment: No I just wanted to know if my approach to original question (the propositions I proposed) if I would have proved those to be true would that have implied that every continuous function has an antiderivative

Comment: O.K, let me look into it.

Comment: @Matt You need to add "a.e." in your last sentence.

Comment: @Matt: I was thinking of the fundamental theorem, Lebesgue version: f is a.e., iff $f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^x h(t)dt $ for h(x) Lebesgue-integrable.

Comment: Oh yea thats stupid of me, I forget that for some reason that $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f$ itself is considered a function. Dumb mistake. @Matt But would the truth of these propositions still imply every continuous function had an antiderivative?

Comment: @DavidMitra: Good catch, David. Unfortunately, it won't let me edit the comment.

Comment: @Matt: you can always delete the comment and write a new one.

Comment: @gary: I think you're answering the wrong question. The Cantor-Lebesgue function is an example of a function f such that f≠∫f′. However, every continuous function has an antiderivative defined by F(x)=∫x0f. In fact, every integrable function has an antiderivative a.e.--this is the Lebesgue differentiation theorem (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem).

Comment: @Matt: yes, I did interpret the question to ask whether $f= \int f'$. Otherwise, like you said, the issue is trivial.

Comment: @Matt: I also think that the OP was referring to "standard differentiation", not the Lebesgue version, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @Matt yes I was thinking of differentiation that is normally defined in intro calc but like I said in above comment I made a stupid mistake

Comment: @user159813: Sorry if I gave myself permission to make assumptions without asking you. Would you still like me to go through your argument with the given assumptions?

Comment: @gary no don't worry about it I understand answer to my question now. Im actually glad you made these assumption because these comments have broaden my view of differentiation I didn't know there where different kinds. I also always love when people give me new examples with strange properties

Comment: @user159813: If you want strangeness, you can count on me ;).

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid that Gary's answer is not precised correctly. The Cantor function ( $C(x)$ from now on)  is continuous at each point of the interval $I:= [0,1]$. Hence, the integral function
$F(x)$ (defined as the integral of $C(x)$ on $[0,x]$ ) is an antiderivative of $C(x)$ on $I$.
Probably you tried to mean that $C(x)$ is not an antiderivative for any function.

Antonio